# Number of points in the intersection of two differential curves

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

If $c_1, c_2$ are two (differents) piecewise differential simple closed curves in $\mathbb R^2$ then the number of points in the intersection of these curves is necessarily a finite set?

Thanks you all for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further restriction, $c_1$ could be equal to $c_2$, and then the statement would be false. Even if the equality is not the case, analogous situations where the curves are equal for a range of the parameter $t$, though not equal over the whole domain, would be counterexamples. Edit for explicit example: Take for instance the unitary circumference centered at the origin as $c_1$, and then the following construction for $c_2$: for $y>0$, it's just the upper half of the circumference; for $y \leq 0$, it is just part of a square of side 2. Then each curve is piecewise differentiable, closed, and their intersection is the whole upper circle (not a finite set), though they are different for $y<0$.

Comment: I have edited the question, I'm sorry

Comment: Added a counterexample. Tell me if something is still "off".

Comment: Can you add some extra hypothesis to get the result?

Comment: Well, it is quite a general and interesting question; I believe, although it is not yet a proof, that if in every intersection point the velocity vectors of the curves are linearly independent, then the result is valid.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto Compare intersections of $ ( \sin x, xy =.01), ( \sin x, xy =10)$